# Updating multiple rows efficiently

Tags: java, mysql

How do i update multiple rows efficiently?

1. One statement
2. Multiple statements

Can a single statement string become too large for SQL to handle (10000+ entries/rows)?

I have one single variable to modify, which is `status`:

```
| id | status |
```

My data is stored in a List (ArrayList).

Comment: Can you please update the need behind the update is it one time in a day or everytime.

Comment: The process is done every hour, but the update amount will vary alot. Worst case at the moment is around 11000 rows at every update.

Comment: Can you explain more about the problem. Single statement updating status based on criteria can do this.

Comment: @ejb_guy, the problem is that i cannot see which way seems to be most efficient. Making all the updates in one string, or taking them one-by-one in a for-loop. I do not know if theres any risk/consequences building a large update string.

Comment: Update table1 set status =<value> where id =<criteria> Can you explain how the value and criteria will be linked or is it based on input from user\external source

Comment: PreparedStatement is compiled once, which make it more effective even if you loop threw it 10k times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be more efficient to use the [Load Data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) command in MySQL.  Provided you can structure your input into CSV format.  Utilize the REPLACE and/or IGNORE keywords appropriately.  This will be much faster than 1000's of individual statements to MySQL.

Comment: My data is stored in a ArrayList, does that change anything?

Comment: Must say this is better way. Write the data in file (assuming that list contains both Id and status), load the data in temp table. After this single and simple update will do the trick

Comment: You would have to write code yourself to write the data in your ArrayList to a temporary csv file on disk and issue the Load Data query referencing that file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use JDBC and do it efficient you should definitely check out [this blog post](http://www.jroller.com/mmatthews/entry/speeding_up_batch_inserts_for) about batch inserts performance (applies to updates too).

Generally speaking you need to add `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` to your connection string, for example:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database_name?rewriteBatchedStatements=true","login", "password");
```

This will allow driver to take prepared statements and re-write them to more efficient form.

Comment: The blog post can be accessed [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150516151157/http://www.jroller.com/mmatthews/entry/speeding_up_batch_inserts_for).

Answer (score 0):

See prepared statements : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Create your prepared statement out of the loop, then inside the loop, just execute prepared statement with updated parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If your *status* is limited set of values, than I will break the list in subsets based on status and than update the set of rows per single statement. Even if there are 10K rows for specific staus, you can update multiple rows (using in operator) in single call. This will decrease the roundtrip that your application need to made for updation.

Answer (score 0):

Also you may try batch updates like this, though I'm not sure whether they are efficient:

```
update `id_status_table` `row`
set `status` = (
    select case `row`.`id` when 1 then 'one'
                           when 2 then 'two'
                           else 'three or more' end
);
```

While  the query string for 10000 rows may get too big, you may apply such query to each 1000 rows.